# Pointer pointing to an element in a vector gets set to NULL when the structure grows

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

A pointer to an object gets set to NULL, despite the fact that there is no `pointerToObj = NULL` anywhere in the function. Later I use that pointer for something and it causes an Access Violation exception. I also added a test pointer to see if it will preserve its value, but no - both get set to NULL at the same time.

The pointer points at an object in a vector. At one point, I add a new object to the vector, so the structure grows. Right after this the pointer gets set to NULL. I tested this - all pointers, that point to a certain element of the vector, get set to NULL right after I add the new object.

I suspect that this happens because of the way the Vectors work - if I am not mistaken, they are based on a Stack. When a stack has to lengthen itself, it must copy itself in a new bigger array and delete the old one. But now the new array is located elsewhere in the memory, so my pointer is no longer pointing in the correct location.

Is this really the case?

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't work the way your describe, that being external pointers getting set to NULL. You need to post code of this behavior.

Comment: Have you validated that the pointer is in fact set to `NULL`? **How?** (Minimal code example?) While dereferencing a null pointer causes an Access Violation (on Windows), the reverse is not true. Access Violations happen with all invalid pointers, not just null pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, adding an element to a `std::vector` may invalidate pointers to its elements for the reason you describe (but it doesn't have anything to do with stacks). Your pointer isn't being magically set to null though, it just points at a non-existent object.

Comment: Adding to this: the solution is that you should not store pointers to objects in a `vector`. Instead, store the index of the object, or use a container which preserves pointers .

Comment: Yeah, I confused a NULL pointer with invalidated pointer. Guess I was in a misconception about how vectors work.

Answer (score 1):

Using **std::vector** to store pointers or objects that have pointer members resets all the pointers to the new vector allocated memory addresses-NULL or any memory address.
You can set the pointer to the value you want after you push it back in the vector instead of setting it before **push_back()**.
For Example, if you have an object called **x** of class client that has pointers, and you want to store it in vector v.
Do this:

```
client x;
v.push_back(x);
static int i = 0;
v[i++].set_name();
```

So, if you called **v[i].get_name()** the pointer will be pointing on the name.

Instead of:

```
client x;
x.set_name();
v.push_back(x);
x.get_name();
```

This will return a random memory address.

Be carful, every time you **push_back()** an element the vector size is doubled, and the first element pointer will point to a new location that fits the doubled size. You can set the first element to a garbage or empty object of type client, or you can reserve vector memory before you do anything with it in order to keep all the addresses as they are. You can see how this is done here: [change of vectors first pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013261/change-of-vectors-first-pointer).